# Reverse letters of words inside text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to reverse letters of words inside text file , example:
input >

```
ABCD :    123 QA    
FGHK :    456 QB
```

output >

```
DCBA :    321 AQ  
KHGF :    654 BQ
```

edit:

some of my unsuccessful solutions :

```
 " ".join(str[::-1].split()[::-1])  
 ''.join([str[i] for i in xrange(len(str)-1, -1, -1)])
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried till now? Add some code, we will help if you get any errors

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @acclav Add it to your question

Comment: Bro you can still read more about file input and output, before posting a question here ...

Comment: I tried , but I dont have any idea how to maintain spaces while reversing the letters so I thought to ask help here

Comment: So that's your real question.

Comment: yeah , because I know how to reverse words in a list for example

Comment: Fix your question then.

Comment: @martineau I don't understand what is wrong with my question ?

Comment: You seem to know how to reverse letters in words, so what you really want to know is how to do it to them in lines of a file while maintaining the spacing between then (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split()` :

```
>>> import re
>>> s ='ABCD :    123 QA'
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x: x[::-1],re.split(r'(\s?)',s)))
'DCBA :    321 AQ'
```

with `r'(\s?)'` pattern you split the string after any whitspace but keep them , so you will have the following list :

```
['ABCD', ' ', ':', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '123', ' ', 'QA']
```

then you can apply your reverse function on your words with `map` and join them at last .

Comment: Thank you , worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
>>> my_string = "ABCD :    123 QA"
>>> "{} {}\t {} {}".format(*map(lambda x:x[::-1],my_string.split()))
'DCBA :\t 321 AQ'
```

Comment: This will crash if any line in the file doesn't contain exactly 4 space-separated values.

Comment: The down vote doesn't come from me, but I notice that the OP's main issue is to maintain the spaces - transforming them into tabs is perhaps not what he wants to do

Comment: @Rawing for OP input its gonna work. OP input dosent contain 4 spaces.

Comment: I gave just an example , I would like a solution for general use